# How to get client fields data with your login key in faunadb?

Tags: faunadb

After login in faunadb, I need to make a query to get your own data in faunadb. I tried this:

```
const data = await faunaClient(faunaSecret).query(
  q.Get(q.Ref(q.Collection('sellers'), q.Identify()))
)
```

In this function I have only client secret key, but not your ref. Maybe I need to make a query to get your id and join with the query to get your data...

Answer (score 0):

OMG, i'm very noob in Fauna Query Languague, it's just add `q.Identity` inside `q.Get`!

```
const data = await faunaClient(faunaSecret).query(q.Get(q.Identity()))
```